# Sober spaces vs. spatial frames-a big picture

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, big-picture, lattice-theory, adjoint-functors

For any topological space $X$ one can consider the so called frame of all open subsets of $X$ to be denoted by $\mathcal{O}(X)$. If $f:X \to Y$ is continuous taking the inverse image we get the morphism between frames $\mathcal{O}(f): \mathcal{O}(Y) \to \mathcal{O}(X)$. In this manner we obtain a contravariant functor. On the other side, for a frame $F$ one can define the space $Pt(F)$ of points of $F$ to be $Hom(F,\{0,1\})$ declaring all the sets of the form $\Phi(U):=\{p \in Pt(F): p(U)=1\}$ as opens. If $g:F \to G$ is a frame morphism we get a continuous map in the opposite direction $Pt(g):Pt(G) \to Pt(F)$ by $Pt(g)(q)=q \circ g$.

A topological space $X$ is called sober if any irreducible subset $A$ of $X$ is a closure of the unique point. This is equivalent to the condition that the map $\delta:X \to Pt(\mathcal{O}(X))$ is a homeomorphism where $\delta_x(U):=1$ if $x \in U$ and $0$ otherwise.

Take $X$ to be *any* topological space (not necessarilly sober). Then even the map $\delta$ need not to be homeomorphism, still $\mathcal{O}(\delta):\mathcal{O}(Pt(\mathcal{O}(X))) \to \mathcal{O}(X)$ is an isomorphism of frames. This isomorphism turns out to be equal to $\Phi^{-1}$. In particular $\mathcal{O}(X)$ is always *spatial* (see below).

Now we would like to repeat the argument but for the other direction: we call a frame $F$ to be spatial if the following condition holds: if it is not true that $a \leq b$ in $F$ then there exists $p \in Pt(F)$ such that $p(a)=1$ and $p(b)=0$. Now it is *not* true that for any frame $F$ the map $Pt(\Phi)$ is always a homeomorphism: it is $\iff$ $Pt(\Phi)$ is surjective $\iff \Phi$ is injective $\iff F$ is spatial. In this case $Pt(\Phi)=\delta^{-1}$.

> Question 1: Is the above reasoning concerning spatiality of $F$ correct?

In particular it is not true that always (i.e. for any frame $F$-not necessarily spatial) $Pt(F)$ is isomorphic to $Pt(\mathcal{O}(Pt(F)))$: it happens precisely when $F$ is spatial which holds iff $Pt(F)$ is sober. I'm pretty sure that I am missing something here: so let me ask

> Question 2: Is the space $Pt(F)$ always sober? Is it true that always $Pt(F) \cong Pt(\mathcal{O}(Pt(F)))$ or it is true precisely when $F$ is spatial?

I would be grateful if someone can clarify these issues.

Comment: Also, in case you're not aware, I think many people's go-to reference for this stuff is Johnstone's _Stone Spaces_.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is always true that $Pt(F) \cong Pt(\mathcal{O}(Pt(F)))$ (i.e. $Pt(F)$ is sober), whether or not $F$ is spatial.  Indeed, this follows formally from the fact that $\mathcal{O}(Pt(\mathcal{O}(X))) \cong \mathcal{O}(X)$ for all spaces $X$, using the theory of [idempotent adjunctions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/idempotent+adjunction).